# Is there a way to run javafx applications in browsers easily?

Tags: java, html, javafx

I have a javafx program that can be compiled and executed as a jar. Im trying to get it to from a html or js file. Is there any reliable way to do that.

Comment: Nope, there is not.

Comment: afaik no. Browsers are no longer bridges between the Internet and client-side apps. There are independent implementations of Java Web Start like OpenJDK IcedTea but i'm not sure how helpful that would be really. With recent JDKs you can build a native installer out of the box.

Comment: thanks, i guess its not possible

Comment: I've never used it, but have a look at [Jpro](https://www.jpro.one/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is still working, but 1-2 years ago, I played around with https://www.jpro.one/
however, you will still need a server running your application, but you will be able to access the UI via a web browser on the specified url path.